# How do I add an image to a specified container in HTML?

Tags: html, css

I made a slideshow on the first row and now have 2 containers beneath the slideshow. Whenever I add an image in place of where the text is add, the image seems to have no restraints to the container and just fills the page. How do I place the images in the container without overflowing? Also, I'd love to make those images links too if that's possible. Currently, I have not created any CSS for this which I'm guessing will be needed.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-2">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Put Some Text Here<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-2">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Or Maybe Over Here<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are right. Using images in the HTML in this case defeats the purpose of the container, for that reason you could only paste the image using "img src".

You leave the container as is and in the CSS you target that container and add the image as background for the container.

```
#container {background-image: url("path/to/image.jpg");}
```

To make the container a link just place the container inside a link element.

```
<a href="link.com"><div id="container"></div></a>
```

Remember to code both HTML and CSS at the same time, not one after the other because many headaches will wait for you.

Comment: Thank you, this was exactly what I needed.